# Gson Parsing with dynamic json keys

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have gone through may posts about dynamic keys parsing. But still confusing on parsing below **JSON** format using **Gson** which is a new response in my existing project.

```
{
    "position":0,
    “source”:[“Win","Web","Capture","iOS","Camera","Back"],
    “source_data”:{
        "Web”:{“years”:[{“start”:1500,"end”:1700}]},
        "Win":{"years":[{"start”:1700,"end”:2000}]},
        "iOS":{"years":[{"start”:1700,"end”:2200}]},
        "Back":{"years":[{"start”:2100,"end”:2300}]},               
        "Camera":{"years":[{"start”:2200,"end":2200},{"start”:2200,"end”:2600},{"start”:2300,"end”:2600}]},
        "Capture":{"years":[{"start”:1700,"end”:2100}]}
    }
}
```

I already having Json Parsing setup using Gson library. 
below is the code snippet with i am using to parse. but **source_data** key's value is not getting stored into my model class

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("source_data")
private SourceData mSourceData;


public class SourceData {

    HashMap<String, SourceYears> mSourceYears;

    public HashMap<String, SourceYears> getSourceYears() {
        return mSourceYears;
    }

    public void setSourceYears(HashMap<String, SourceYears> years) {
        this.mSourceYears = years;
    }
}

public class SourceYears {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("years")
    private List<Years> mYears;

    public List<Years> getYears() {
        return mYears;
    }

    public void setYears(List<Years> years) {
        this.mYears = years;
    }
}
```

here `Years` is the class with contain `start` & `end` keys.

please suggest if some one identified what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm it should work, I wonder that in your json has 2 type character “years” and "years"

Comment: @CôngHải I could not understand your question. its only one key "years". which you mentioned 2 times. I was confused and thinking ewy its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this, i have refined models based on json you provided, also the json you provided is not accurate due to wrong double quotes.

Here are my Pojo Classes

```
class YearWrapper {
        List<YearObject> years;

        public List<YearObject> getYears() {
            return years;
        }

        public void setYears(List<YearObject> years) {
            this.years = years;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "YearWrapper{" +
                    "years=" + years +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class YearObject {
        int start;
        int end;

        public int getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public void setStart(int start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        public int getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        public void setEnd(int end) {
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "YearObject{" +
                    "start=" + start +
                    ", end=" + end +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class KeyValueMapModel {
        int position;
        List<String> source;
        @SerializedName("source_data")
        Map<String, YearObject> sourceData;

        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public void setPosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public List<String> getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        public void setSource(List<String> source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        public Map<String, YearObject> getSourceData() {
            return sourceData;
        }

        public void setSourceData(Map<String, YearObject> sourceData) {
            this.sourceData = sourceData;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "KeyValueMapModel{" +
                    "position=" + position +
                    ", source=" + source +
                    ", sourceData=" + sourceData +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Here is how i am invoking it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
KeyValueMapModel keyValueMapModel = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, KeyValueMapModel.class);
System.out.println(keyValueMapModel);
```

Comment: what the use of YearWrapper class here. it seems that class is not used.